# Integral of $\log(1+x^{-2})$

Tags: integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

How can I find the integral of this function:
$f(x) =\int{\log(1+\frac{1}{x^2})}dx$ 
What technique should I use?

Answer (score 5):

$\int \log \frac{x^2+1}{x^2} dx= \int \log (x^2+1)dx -2\int \log x dx$

Both intrgrals can be found by integration by parts.

Comment: applied integration by parts, got  $x\log \frac{x^2+1}{x^2}+2\arctan(x)$